# RUN npm install get /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

Tags: node.js, docker

I would like to run npm install in a separated RUN.

Here is the dockerfile

```
RUN  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
&& export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
&& [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
&& nvm install node && nvm use node \
&& npm cache clean -f && npm install -g n && n stable && npm install cross-env \
&& npm install \
&& npm run dev
```

In this case, npm install works

but when I convert it to:

```
RUN  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
&& export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
&& [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
&& nvm install node && nvm use node \
&& npm cache clean -f && npm install -g n && n stable && npm install cross-env

RUN npm install
RUN npm run dev
```

it says

```
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
```

Why ???

Comment: If you haven't sourced `nvm.sh` into the individual shell instance, that shell doesn't have the `nvm` function available. Each `RUN` starts a new shell, so it won't have environment variables and functions that were local to prior ones.

Comment: I didn't know each RUN open a new terminalm tx for the info

Comment: Maybe I should remove a \ in && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \ to source it

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me: https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/aacf14c29b3f01d6900d13137b21db3a

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 15.8.0
RUN apt update\
    && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash\
    && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh\
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION
ENV NODE_PATH /root/.nvm/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH /root/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```