# Getting not found error when trying to run globally installed npm module in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I tried to install modules like `typescript` `nodemon` and `jazelle` globally in my Dockerfile like so

```
RUN npm i -g <module name>
RUN <nodemon/typescript/jazelle>  # only one of these
```

and I'd get this error when building the image:

```
/bin/sh: <nodemon/typescript/jazelle>: not found
```

I saw something similar here but it doesn't seem to answer the question for globally installed npm modules: [RUN npm install get /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310268/run-npm-install-get-bin-sh-1-npm-not-found) . Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: for more context, I'm trying to use jazelle and avoid having a root level package.json.  this is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /common

RUN npm i -g jazelle --unsafe-perm

COPY ./common ./

RUN jazelle init # also tried npx jazelle init and it always fails here

COPY manifest.json ./

COPY ./common/package*.json ./

COPY ./common/yarn.lock ./

RUN jazelle install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# start work on auth
WORKDIR /auth

COPY ./auth/package*.json ./

COPY ./auth/yarn.lock ./

RUN jazelle install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run", "build"]

FROM node:alpine
ENV CI=true

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /auth/build .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: Did you try to run them both in one `RUN` using `&&`?

Comment: @Anatoly I did not. I'm only running one. I'd ultimately only be using jazelle only but gave the other modules as examples to broaden the scope of my question.

Comment: Are those dependencies listed in your `package.json` file?  If so, you shouldn't need to separately `npm install` them, though you may need to run them with an `npx` wrapper to add the right directories to your path (`RUN npx tsc ...`).  Scripts in your `package.json` file will get this automatically.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm hoping not to add a `package.json` to the root of my monorepo.  I identified the issue to the inability to run globally installed modules per what I described above and perhaps there's a more standard solution to my problem?  I'll update the post to give fuller context as well.

Comment: If the subpackages need `jazelle` to build, list it in their `package.json` `"devDependencies"`.  You probably won't notice any practical issues from it being installed twice.

Comment: Did you try to do like in this link https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#global-npm-dependencies